# How to prove that a particular polyiamond tiles the Euclidean plane?

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

I read that among the 24 heptiamonds there is one piece that does not tile the Euclidean plane. My question is the following, given a particular polyiamond how do you prove that the piece does tile the Euclidean plane? ( I thought about arranging the pieces and possibly stretching the piece to a form of which it is known that it tiles the plane, i.e. triangle, square, parallelogram or hexagon. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The V heptiamond will not tile the plane. All others will.

The proof of tiling is usually to find a tiling. That's often very simple for the smaller iamonds, polyhexes, and polyominoes.

For larger polyforms, such as the wheelbarrow polyhex, finding the tiling can be quite tricky.   See the [tiling database](http://www.polyomino.org.uk/mathematics/polyform-tiling/) for more.

Comment: Can you be more precise about when a tiling has been found. What is the exact criterium for that? Imagine an algorithm doing so, what would be the stop rule?

Comment: [Octiamond tilings](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/octtes.html) -- When a repeated tiling with translation is found, you've divided the plane into identical cells with identical orientation. Each cell will have some number of of polyforms.

Comment: That's a nice page, there is one about the heptiamonds too. Anyway, I had hoped that there was a way to a priori say, from its properties, that the V-shape does not tile the plane.

Comment: With the V shape, lay down one.  To fill the hole, the next piece is forced.  To fill that hole, the next move is forced. A few more forced moves gives unfillable holes.  Generally, the non-tilers cannot surround themselves, the [Heesch problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heesch's_problem), but there are many non-tilers that are Heesch-2.